# Two Drives Dual Boot with Secure Boot

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, ssd, secure-boot, dualboot

I'm going to build a PC with two SSD’s. I want to have Windows on one SSD and Ubuntu on the other. Why? This pc is going to be for educational and private use. I'm planning to use Ubuntu for school and Windows for private stuff and gaming.

Before I start building, I just want to make sure if this is possible, and that it's not meaningless doing as I'm planning, lol.

I'll first and foremost try installing Ubuntu with Secure Boot, but since I've heard that many people have had issues with Ubuntu's support for Secure Boot I might just disabling this feature for Ubuntu.

If this happens, can I still use Secure Boot for Windows? Like, every time before launching Windows I just enable Secure Boot again to make sure that it's the legit Windows Boot Loader that gets booted? If I also then have my Windows SSD encrypted, wouldn't that be a way of protecting my Windows data from potential root kits and similar?

Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: Are aware that Secure Boot is supported by Ubuntu?  Why exactly are you going to install Windows with Secure Boot enabled?  Just install it with it disabled. Secure Boot is optional.

Comment: meaningless.. yes. IMHO.. what @ramhound said

Comment: Re: @Ramhound . Ubuntu supports Secure Boot: Yes, I know. But I've read that people having issues whit this support, and that they usually just disables secure boot for Ubuntu anyways. Why Windows with Secure Boot? Because most malware is targeted at Windows, and if Secure Boot is an option, why not have it enabled? And I guess you must have it enabled during Windows installation, otherwise, when do the boot software signature get generated? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Re: @SeñorCMasMas . Haha, happy that you LUHO! Maybe you can explain in more detail then, why it is meaningless? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Meaningless that you somehow care about secure boot in one configuration but not in another with the same media exposed.  Honestly, I meant no offense.. this whole thing *seems* silly to me.

Comment: If your going to just disable it in order to install Ubuntu, my question was, why enable it in the first place.  Secure Boot won’t prevent malware.  You either enable it and install the operating systems or disable it, Secure Boot serves a purpose, but it won’t prevent what you are worried about

Comment: Ok, I’m glad you’re here discussing with me. As I've understood (maybe I'm wrong), the Secure Boot process uses a certificate stored in the UEFI to authenticate OS software before it executes. With that being said, to avoid root kits to replace my Windows boot loader (for example), if I enable Secure Boot before launching Windows, and if it boots normally, shouldn't that verify that it's the legit Windows that has been booted? If I then also have the Windows ssd encrypted, shouldn't the data on that media more or less be inaccessible if Secure Boot stops Windows from booting?

Comment: I updated my Question according to what we have discussed.